# Display value from <Select> in the form

Tags: html

I have my HTML code similar to the below code.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select id="cars" name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>
  <h1> </h1>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here in the same form, I need to display the selected value in the  tag.

Could someone guide how I can display the selected value in the  tag as user makes the selection from the dropdown?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select id="cars" name="cars" onchange="document.getElementById('tag').innerText=this.value;">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>
  <h1 id="tag"> </h1>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```